# adding absolute path but keeping relative paths intact

Tags: ant

hi i have an existing ant script `build.xml` that has all the paths as relative paths.

I was wondering if i could add a line or somewhere that will allow me to add an absolute path so that i can leave the relative paths intact and work?

i tried adding `basedir="C:\Work\"` to `<project>` but it doesnt work.

for example,

in my `build.xml` i have:

```
<exec executable="Build\file.exe">
```

and this `build\file.exe` is located in `C:\Work\build\file.exe`. However, if i use a console application to run `C:\Work\ant.bat` which will trigger my `build.xml` (ant script) and this

```
<exec executable="Build\file.exe">
```

would not function. Hence i would like to add a absolute path to my script so that i can keep all my relative paths intact. Anybody knows of any possible ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the problem paths are used in `exec` as you have shown, you could resolve this by setting your `PATH` environment variable to the full path to the dir containing `Build`, e.g.

```
set PATH=C:\Work;%PATH%
```

This way, the operating system will resolve the path for you.

However, it might be simpler to use a text editor to do a global find/replace so you can use an absolute path in your build file, e.g.

```
<property name="build.tools.dir" value="C:/Work"/>
<exec executable="${build.tools.dir}/Build/file.exe"/>
```